# Getting well known text from varchar in redshift.

Tags: postgis, geometry, well-known-text, well-known-binary

As you know, redshift does not support geometry types. There is a column in a dataset on my redshift db that has varchar column and the format looks like:

```
01060000000000000000___________________________
```

on and on for 765 characters. Since it looks like at some point it was a geometry type, I want to convert this into WKT with hopes of then converting to geom using 'ST_GeomFromText'. I feel like I may be complicating this more than it has to be, I've never worked with WKT so if you have suggestions on how to achieve the same result with a more simple approach I'd prefer that.

I've added a new column using:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','wkt_regions','geomm',4326,'Polygon',2);
```

and later:

```
ALTER TABLE wkt_regions ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Polygon) USING st_astext(left(geometry, 764));
```

Without the left function to trim the geometry I get an error that says " Invalid hex string, length (765) has to be a multiple of two!"
But with it, I get an error that says "WKB structure does not match expected size!"

Comment: That example would describe a MultiPolygon containing zero polygons, which should have 18 characters (9 bytes). Are you really sure this is geometry data?

Comment: @CL. I can't be entirely sure, I just thought it might be because of the format. Currently, it's stored in a redshift db which does not support geometry but I was hoping I could grab the varchar and turn it into a geometry type. Perhaps my way of explaining the problem is not accurate, I'm still somewhat new to GIS on the databases side

Comment: as @CL. mentioned, the WKT geometry structure is of type *MultiPolygon* and is parsed without error with the first 764 characters...with the example being an empty geometry, though. it might just work with the column type set to *MultiPolygon*. if that actually yield any useful results...well, that remains to be seen. btw., if you have created the column accordingly using `AddGeometryColumn` you can simply `UPDATE wkt_table SET geom = ST_Astext(left(geometry, 764));`.